# Calculate Revenue Recognition Per Month in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the order lines which show the Booking Amount and the booked date, but the revenue is recognised over 3 months (so 1/3 in the booked month and a further 1/3 in each of the next 2 months).

I need to create a query that would show the total revenue recognised in each month.

Is there an analytic function that could work this out? as at the moment I have cobbled together 3 joined queries that give the number but in 3 seperate columns, where I need it in one column:

```
select     TRUNC(OM.BOOKING_DATE, 'MONTH') as Month
          , SUM(OM.BOOKED_VALUE)/3 as Month_1 
          , M2.Month_2
          , M3.Month_3

from      ORDERS.OM,
          (select    TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,1), 'MONTH') as Month
                   , SUM(OM.BOOKED_VALUE)/3 as Month_2

           from      ORDERS.OM

           GROUP By TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,1), 'MONTH')) M2,
          (select    TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,2), 'MONTH') as Month
                   , SUM(OM.BOOKED_VALUE)/3 as Month_3

           from      ORDERS.OM
           GROUP By TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,2), 'MONTH')) M3

WHERE     TRUNC(OM.BOOKING_DATE, 'MONTH') = M2.MONTH
AND       TRUNC(OM.BOOKING_DATE, 'MONTH') = M3.MONTH
 
GROUP By TRUNC(OM.BOOKING_DATE, 'MONTH'), M2.Month_2, M3.Month_3

Order by 1 DESC
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Triple every row and sum

```
select   t.Month, SUM(t.Val) as Value
from      ORDERS.OM
cross join lateral (select TRUNC(OM.BOOKING_DATE, 'MONTH') as Month, OM.BOOKED_VALUE/3.0 as Val from dual union all
      select TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,1), 'MONTH'), OM.BOOKED_VALUE/3.0  from dual union all 
      select TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(OM.BOOKING_DATE,2), 'MONTH'), OM.BOOKED_VALUE/3.0  from dual ) t
group by t.Month
```